# How to install windows application and SQL server on the client machine?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to install my c# windows application on a client place which does not have .NET framework or SQL server. What files do I need to install in order for the application to work with database and how to create a package?

Comment: Install the Exe and copy the database mdf and ldf files in the client place to work.

Answer (score 4):

Create a setup project from Visual Studio and specify in the prerequisitesto include .NET framework and SQL Server Express. these packages will then be included in the setup or I think you can also specify to download automatically on setup execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClickOnce deployment for this. With ClickOnce you will give the client an install package that can check for prerequisites and install them if neccesarry. The .NET framework and SqlServer express can be installed this way.

Check the following link for more info: [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/748fh114.aspx)